# Fold with markers, but disable nesting?

Tags: folding

I want to fold sections in a document. Each new section should define a top-level fold instead of a nested fold. I want to use a single delimiter to define a fold. Consider an example document:

```
>>> first fold
also in first fold
>>> second fold
still in second fold
```

I want to fold like this:

```
+----2 lines: first fold
+----2 lines: second fold
```

Using `foldnestmax=0` does not affect `foldmethod=marker`, it only works on `indent` and `syntax` fold methods. Using `foldmarker=>>>,>>>` does not work, it creates nested folds. The only option I have found is to use fold numbers, e.g. `>>>1 first fold`, but I'd like to avoid that. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with a *fold expression*. Cp. `:help fold-expr`. When the current line starts with your fold marker `>>>`, start a new fold (of level 1); else, continue with the same level as before:

```
setlocal foldmethod=expr foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~#'^>>>'?'>1':'='
```

Comment: I removed the hash (not sure what it's for), and I want to match anywhere in the line, so I removed the caret, and I had to escape special characters to use it in my modeline, but it works: `" vim:set foldmethod=expr foldexpr=getline(v\:lnum)=~\'>>>\'?\'>1\'\:\'=\' foldlevel=0 foldclose= :`

Comment: Great! The `=~#` is for case-sensitive matching; it doesn't matter here (but I like to be explicit). You could define a `:function` in your vimrc and reference that in the modeline; would save you from the escaping (and repetition).